# Serverless Deployment to staging domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-route53

I am trying to deploy an API to the domain name in AWS using Serverless Framework. I want to be able to pass in the stage as an option and deploy to that custom domain name.
For example, stage `dev` should make `dev-api.firstcivdivcareers.com`.

I have the domain in Route53, created public certificates for the possible domains, but when I run the command I get the error below. It's either the way I am trying to use options and variables in serverless or something I am not setting up in AWS.

Still learning how to use serverless so any advice or commands I can use to debug is appreciated.

**Error**:

```
$ serverless deploy --stage dev
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting with next major version, API Gateway naming will be changed from "{stage}-{service}" to "{service}-{stage}".
            Set "provider.apiGateway.shouldStartNameWithService" to "true" to adapt to the new behavior now.
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#AWS_API_GATEWAY_NAME_STARTING_WITH_SERVICE
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
Serverless: No external modules needed
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Installing dependencies for custom CloudFormation resources...
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Unable to fetch information about undefined
      at APIGatewayWrapper.<anonymous> (/Users/kyle/Code/firstcivdivcareers/serverless/JobPostsAPI/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/src/aws/api-gateway-wrapper.js:109:27)
      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at rejected (/Users/kyle/Code/firstcivdivcareers/serverless/JobPostsAPI/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/src/aws/api-gateway-wrapper.js:6:65)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              12.18.0
     Framework Version:         2.25.2
     Plugin Version:            4.4.3
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        3.7.0
```

**Serverless.yaml**:

```
service: jobpostsapi
app: firstcivdivcareers
org: kycalica

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain: ${opt:stage}-api.firstcivdivcareers.com
  domainName: ${opt:stage}-api.firstcivdivcareers.com
  basePath: ''
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  endPointType: regional
  certificateName: '_90e79ed1be1d0eac6e388ed7c2f865d2.firstcivdivcareers.com'
  createRoute53Record: true
  enabled: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221


functions:
  payment:
    handler: handler.payment
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: '/payment'
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with the domain manager plugin. I'd recommend asking of the creator of that plugin specifically.

Comment: Also, perhaps try with a more recent version of the framework. There has been some work on the variables resolver recently that may have affected what you are trying to do and possibly fixed in later versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to fix the indentation in the `custom` section. The `domainName` and `basePath` should be under `customDomain`:

```
custom:
  customDomain:
     domainName: ${opt:stage}-api.firstcivdivcareers.com
```

`baseName` is optional, so if you don't need it, just don't include it.

Comment: thanks that worked. it said it mapped the domain but it never actually did. so I will have to dig into that.

Comment: If you want you can set SLS_DEBUG=* before running the deployment and send it over.

Comment: well I have this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224273/serverless-command-create-domain-not-found