# Serverless command "create_domain" not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-route53

I keep getting the `create_domain` command not found in my serverless project.
I have installed `serverless-domain-manager` in the project AND globally now.
Still does not work either way.

serverless.yml:

```
service: jobsapi
app: civdivcareers
org: kycalica

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
 - serverless-bundle
 - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: dev-api.civdivcareers.com
  certificateName: '*.civdivcareers.com'
  stage: dev
  createRoute53Record: true
  endPointType: regional
  enabled: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221


functions:
  payment:
    handler: handler.payment
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: '/payment'
```

Error:

```
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Serverless command "create_domain" not found. Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              12.18.0
     Framework Version:         2.35.0
     Plugin Version:            4.5.3
     SDK Version:               4.2.2
     Components Version:        3.8.3
```

Serverless plugin list output:

```
$ sls plugin list | grep domain
    aws-cognito-idp-userpool-domain - Manage (add and remove) aws hosted domain on Cognito Userpools
    serverless-api-cloudfront - Plugin that adds CloudFront distribution in front of your API Gateway for custom domain, CDN caching and access log.
    serverless-certificate-creator - This serverless plugin creates certificates that you need for your custom domains in API Gateway.
    serverless-domain-manager - Serverless plugin for managing custom domains with API Gateways.
    serverless-plugin-custom-domain - Reliably sets a BasePathMapping to an API Gateway Custom Domain
    serverless-website-domain - A plugin that creates Route 53 records that point to your Cloudfront hosted static website, including www/non-www redirects.
```

Comment: Can you verify that the plugin is installed? I.e. if you do `sls help` is `ServerlessCustomDomain` in the list of plugins? I had issues installing `serverless-domain-manager` via `sls plugin install` so I ended up installing it manually via npm/yarn and then adding it to the `serverless.yml`.

Comment: added my output and i have it.

Comment: Have the same issue, created a bugreport here now https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9426

Comment: Hello @KyleCalica-St - could you share which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: "serverless-domain-manager": "^5.1.0"

Comment: Check that your serverless.ts / .yml can be referenced

Comment: @JasonMullings sorry I don't know what you mean, like proper valid yml?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Yes, I had my serverless.ts in the .gitIgnore folder, which wasn't being reference, throw this error..

Comment: @JasonMullings it is referenced. i believe i mustve installed serverless wrong on my mac.